# print error while null value for SQL safety

Tags: if-statement, jtextfield

How can I print "Error" while the `JTextfield` is empty

```
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String sn =jX1.getText();
        if (sn==null){
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.println("T");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: `System.out` will write to the terminal.  If you *wanted* to write to the terminal I'd imagine that you'd do this, but you don't make it clear if you want to do that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fail-safe method. Also Expanding on the comments, you should be logging data, in a better format. Java hosts a huge array of different way to log certain data. [look here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/top-10-tips-on-logging-in-java.html)

As for your error handling, try-catch-finally. This isn't tested code. Let me know if you run into any issues, documentation on try-catch and other statements [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=25) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (String sn == null)
    try {
         String sn = JX1.getText();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown!");
    }  finally {
    if (sn != null) { 
        System.out.println("Closing PrintWriter");
        sn.close();
    } else { 
        System.out.println("PrintWriter not open");
    } 
}
```